# node serialport writes on PL2303 but not on the attached device

Tags: python, node.js, usb, node-serialport

I have an AllSky-340 CCD camera, which communicates using a serial port.

I use a PL2303 USB converter to connect it to my laptop.

dmesg:

```
[14223.043367] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[14223.172348] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=067b, idProduct=2303
[14223.172352] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[14223.172353] usb 1-2: Product: USB-Serial Controller
[14223.172355] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: Prolific Technology Inc.
[14223.172763] pl2303 1-2:1.0: pl2303 converter detected
[14223.173356] usb 1-2: pl2303 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
```

A python code called [pyallsky](https://github.com/badders/pyallsky) allows to control the AllSky340 camera  under linux. It works.

I have translated this code in javascript to be used with node.

Here is a part of the code code (`"E:"` is a test command):

```
var serialport = require("serialport");                                                                                                         
var sp = new serialport(portName);                                                                                                              

sp.on('open',  showPortOpen);                                                                                                                   
sp.on('close', showPortClose);                                                                                                                  
sp.on('disconnect', showPortDisconnect);                                                                                                        
sp.on('error', showError);                                                                                                                      
sp.on('data',  sendSerialData);                                                                                                                 

function showPortOpen(error) {                                                                                                                  

    if (error) {                                                                                                                                
        console.log('Error while opening the port ' + error);                                                                                   
    } else {                                                                                                                                    
        console.log('port open. Data rate: ' + sp.options.baudRate);                                                                            
        var buffer = "E:"                                                                                                                       
        sp.write(buffer, function (err, result) {                                                                                               
            console.log("writing buffer: "+buffer)                                                                                              
            if (err) {                                                                                                                          
                console.log('Error while sending message : ' + err);                                                                            
            }                                                                                                                                   
            if (result) {                                                                                                                       
                console.log('Response received after sending message : ' + result);                                                             
            }                                                                                                                                   
        });                                                                                                                                     

    }                                                                                                                                           
}                                                                                                                                               

function sendSerialData(data) {                                                                                                                 
    console.log('sendserial data says: '+data);                                                                                                 
}                                                                                                                                               

function showPortClose() {                                                                                                                      
    console.log('port closed.');                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                               

function showPortDisconnect() {                                                                                                                 
    console.log('port disconnected.');                                                                                                          
}                                                                                                                                               

function showError(error) {                                                                                                                     
    console.log('Serial port error: ' + error);                                                                                                 
}
```

But it does not work: running the script, the log is

```
port open. Data rate: 9600
writing buffer: E:
```

and nothing from the camera is recieved.

I do know that the *data listener works*, because if I run the `pyallsky` python script at the same time, my listener intercepts data (before `pyallsky` complains multiple accesses to the port).

Shutting down the camera does not have any effect on `close` and `disconnect` listener.

*Only unplugging the PL2303 cable* causes the script to log

```
port disconnected.
port closed.
```

My idea is that `js` code communicates only with the PL2303 cable and not with the camera. Is that possible?
How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I had to force the baudrate to 115200 in order to make it work.

```
   /// Opens the serial connection with the camera                                                                                              
   var sp = new serialport("/dev/ttyUSB0",                                                                               
                            {baudRate: 115200,                                                    
                             autoOpen:false},                                                                                                   
                            err => err!== null ? 
        console.log('serialport instance error: ', err.message) : true                                  
                           );
```